# Run script from dock in Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, path, sublimetext3, ruby-test

I am developing web applications using Ruby on Rails and Sublime Text 3 on OS X 10.8.4. I recently installed the package [RubyTest](https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests). The tests only work when Sublime is launched using the command

```
subl
```

in terminal. Otherwise I get the error message:

```
/bin/sh: rspec: command not found
```

I think that's meant to be the case; that's implied in RubyTest's readme file on github.

However I'd like to retain the ability to launch from the dock. Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, OSX applications do not pick up on your `$PATH` variable set in Terminal. To change the internal PATH settings in Mountain Lion (this method hasn't been tested with previous versions, although it should work), you'll need to edit `/etc/launchd.conf`:

1. Make sure you have admin privileges.
2. Open Terminal or your favorite substitute and see if there's anything in the file `/etc/launchd.conf`:

   ```
   cat /etc/launchd.conf
   ```

   If you get an error like

   > cat: /etc/launchd.con: No such file or directory

   then continue with the next step. If the `cat` command does display some content, copy it to the clipboard.
3. Create a new text file with the following content, modified to fit your needs:

   ```
   setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/YourUserName/bin:/path/to/gems/bin
   ```

   If the `cat` command displayed some content in the previous step, paste it into the new file **before** the `setenv PATH` command. If it already contains a `setenv PATH` command, just modify it to add the directories you need, such as `/path/to/gems/bin`
4. Save the new file *in your home directory* (`/Users/YourUserName`) as `launchd.conf`.
5. Go back to Terminal and enter:

   ```
   sudo mv ~/launchd.conf /etc
   ```

   to use admin power to move the new file to `/etc`, replacing anything that was there before. Depending on your previous usage of the [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) command, you may get a short "be careful doing what you're doing" message, but either way you'll need to enter your password. `/etc` is not directly accessible through the Save dialog unless you're a real power user and know how to get around OSX's file system restrictions.
6. ***Reboot your computer***

And you should be all set. If you're interested, [`launchd`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html) and [`launchctl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html) use the `csh`/`tcsh` syntax, so you can't use the `bash`/`zsh` `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:...` format.

Comment: path to gems? what about rvm?

Comment: @antiqe as I mentioned in my answer, you can add whatever paths you want. However, `rvm` is generally loaded into your shell session as a function, so there's no path to add for that. You **can** add a path to your current Ruby interpreter if you're using RVM, though.